# Installing a WSP does not update my custom master page

Tags: 2010, solution-package

I have a SharePoint 2010 solution that I develop in Visual Studio 2012. I have a custom master page that I made some changes to. When I publish the .WSP and deploy to my stage environment the changes I made to the master page  do not show up. Why are my changes not getting deployed when I install the updated WSP file on my staging site?

As an aside I am an experienced developer but new to SharePoint so there is probably something obvious I am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to reactivite the feature containing the module that contains you master page

Comment: Does that mean going ot the Site Collection Administration -> Features and then clicking the "Deactivate" then "Activate" buttons?

Comment: Yes, if the scope of your feature is Site